# Writing an algorithm to complete a checklist, where to start?

Tags: algorithm

I'm completing a dissertation in health economics and would like to explore the possibility of using an algorithm to answer a checklist that I manually filled in during my research.

The checklist is a 24-item checklist which asks questions such as "Was a discount rate reported?". Now, the articles I've been reviewing tend to be very codified. That is, there are only a few ways that they report an answer (e.g. "we discounted at 3% in this evaluation").

Theoretically, I think it would be possible to write a program that could search text and fill out the majority of these checklist items. However, I have very little experience in programming. As far as I can see, a program like this would involve writing an algorithm of sorts, but that is where my knowledge ends.

Particularly, I would like to know
- Is this possible?
- If so, how would I go about exploring this further? Ideally, I'd like to get to a point where I could play around with writing an algorithm to look through my database.

Comment: So you want a program to "read" and parse a text? [*Natural language processing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (or *NLP* for short) is a very complex process, there are libraries to help you though. Also remember that [*OCR*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) is not perfect.

Comment: In the world, every human are different with others in every aspect, we cannot 100% what they will answer on a same question. Well, you can try to do something like AI, to do basic prediction based on certain condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could definitely be done with simple logic and parsing, but the key to it would be that the manual entries are consistent in the way that they are "codified".

For example, you'd parse your line for a specific token (or validation word).

> In your case above you could parse word for word the string: "we discounted at 3% in this evaluation"

Code wise we could implement a basic logical comparison to each word parsed in the string.

```
if(currentWord is equal to "discounted") 
    create a checkmark.
```

Comment: Additionally, you could create a dictionary of words that qualify as validators. Then from there you could compare each word in a line being parsed to all the words in the dictionary.

Here's a question for you: What is your database currently in? Doc form? Semi-Colon delimited lists? Excel? Access?

Comment: My database is in excel currently, however the information that is included in the excel spreadsheet is taken from published articles, that are commonly in pdf format. From a cursory read, it seems like pdfs are a nuisance to work with, and so I'd need to extract that to text.

Comment: In that case i'd strongly suggest looking into Excel VBA (Lots of good tutorials out there!)

If the articles lay the information out cleanly and in straight forward text, then you may be able to extract the information with some sort of software into a comma delimited form to be read into excel. Look into tech like: http://tabula.technology/ or the like...